# Cannot find -lhighgui , -lcv, -lcxcore. OpenCV + CodeBlock (Windows 7 )

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, mingw, codeblocks

So I want use codeblock as IDE for my OpenCV program.
I use CodeBlock 12.11, OpenCV-2.4.6.0, with MinGW and Cmake.
I try to follow this tutorial http://kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/opencv-install-on-windows-with-codeblocks-and-mingw/

When I try with simple program like open a image it work. but when I want make program for face recognition, I find this problem.

it is at Build Message:

```
   ld.exe     cannot find -lhighgui
   ld.exe     cannot find -lcv
   ld.exe     cannot find -lcxcore
```

And it is at BuildLog

```
   C:/mingw/...../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lhighgui
   C:/mingw/...../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcv
   C:/mingw/...../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcxcore
   Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
   3 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem please?

Comment: those libs came with opencv1.0 (long time ago) and do no more exist. your tutorial is probably outdated, so try to find something more recent, please. (the code there might be unsusable as well, nowadays)

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html

Comment: so.. the problem at my face recognition tutorial right? thank you once again @berak